# Listing top N files from FTP directory

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I have a requirement to read first 100 files from FTP directory and process those after downloading.

I can't rely on whole list of files obtained in first call because some new files will be added and removed during processing. My program is expected to keep running while there are new files in directory.

I wrote the following code to read all files and take only first 100 from those.

```
List<FileHolder> list = new List<FileHolder>();
int filesToRead = 100;

FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = GetFtpRequest(directoryPath);
ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();

using (Stream responseStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    if (responseStream != null)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                var split = line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (split.Length > 3)
                {
                    var fileName = split[split.Length-1];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) && split[2].ToLower() != "<dir>" && line.Contains(".xml"))
                    {
                        var ftpFile = new FileHolder
                        {
                            FileName = fileName
                        };
                        list.Add(ftpFile);

                        //break on desired max number of files
                        if (list.Count == filesToRead)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}

ftpResponse.Close();
```

Is there any other way or specific FTP method to get only top `N` files because I have to call this method iteratively.

Comment: What are the first 100 files?  Is it by time or in alphabetical order or just the order that they are arranged in the directory?

Comment: It is just the order that they are arranged. Files are placed like 111.xml, 112.xml ..... 299.xml and can be processed in any order. I just have to take chunks of whole set. During processing I have to move those files hence I can not rely on previously obtained list.

Comment: The use FTP Get directory.  Then get files one at time that haven't previously be read or ones that have changed based on time.  If a file is 1 meg byte you do not want to keep on getting the same file if it hasn't changed.  So you have to compare the time of files received with the list that is in the remote folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any other way or specific FTP method to get only top N files because I have to call this method iteratively.

No. You have to retrieve whole directory listing and select your "top 100 files" afterwards. Exactly as you are doing already.